# elasticsearch sum request by clientip (iis logs)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get the number of request by ip address in the last 5 minutes. I am getting the requests with this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": "now-5m",
            "to": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now I want to add the request with the same clientip field, I know I'll need to use aggregations but I don't know how exactly to construct the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the the field 'ipaddress' is not tokenized:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "from": "now-5m",
                        "to": "now"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   },
   "aggs": {
        "ipaddress": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ipaddress"
            }
        }
    }
}
```